# How can i change canvas background color with " input color and onchange "

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

My teacher gave me homework, but he didn't explain the details. He just said "write JS codes to change canvas background with color input and onChange event". So far, I have tried this but I am stuck:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px; background:red ; color:blue ">
</canvas>
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
  <input type="color"  onchange="?">

</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('canvas1').style.background = "green";
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. What you could do is add a parameter for myFunction which would be a reference of the input to itself, then use that to set the value. Here's an example of what I mean:

Change the input to this:

```
<input type="color"  onchange="myFunction(this)">
```

And change the function to this:

```
function myFunction(self) {
    document.getElementById('canvas1').style.background = self.value;
}
```